# Detecting "/' in R

Tags: r, stringr

I am working in RStudio with a data frame which has columns that contains dates. Some rows contains years such as 1687, others contains dates format such as 12/12/23 and others contains characters such as "First half of 19e century". I am trying to extract numerical values from this columns.

The way I went about it to extract numerical values from all rows expect the one that contains "/" because I want to keep those as it is. Here is my code:

```r
detect<-str_detect("/", MR_all$period)
MR_all$period[detect=FALSE]

MR_all['period_3']=dplyr::case_when(MR_all$period[detect=FALSE]~gsub("\\D", "",MR_all$period))
```

This does not work because the detect functions fails to detect the slash and prints all observations. I'd really appreciate your help in writing a function that detects '/'

Comment: Hmm... I took a look at the doc and I think the first argument should be the string and not the pattern. Maybe switch your arguments?  Such as ```detect<-str_detect(string=MR_all$period,pattern= "/")```

Comment: Maybe another question... Is ```MR_all$period``` a string? Try ```type_of(MR_all$period)```. If not, perhaps try converting it to a string? Like ```MR_all$new_column <- as_string(MR_all$period)```

Answer (score 2):

1. You're using a single `=` for comparison, as in `[detect=FALSE]`, which is going to return *nothing*, c.f., `mtcars$cyl[detect=FALSE]` (with or without `detect` previously assigned, this does not check nor use it if it exists).

   Why? Because a single `=` is an *assignment*, so in the case you are creating (in this case, overwriting) an object named `detect` with a single value, `FALSE`. Because assignment invisibly returns the assigned value to the calling portion, this means that the `[..]` around it is passed a single `FALSE`. Effectively, `MR_all$period[FALSE]` is what you're telling R you want to do, and it happily returns a 0-length vector (likely `character(0)`, but I'm guessing ... see #2).
2. Since you are using `str_detect("/", MR_all$period)`, this suggests that `MR_all$period` is a column of *strings* (`character` class), so your next use of `MR_all$period[detect==FALSE] ~ gsub(..)` seems wrong: the left-hand side (LHS) of the `~` pairs in `case_when` must resolve as logical, so `a_string ~ gsub(..)` is wrong.
3. Further, even if `MR_all$period[detect==FALSE]` did resolve to something logical so that `case_when` will continue, we then have the problem where this vector is shorter than the number of rows in the original frame, yet you're reassigning this shorter-vector back into the entire `MR_all['period_3']`, which *if you're lucky* will warn or fail, but if you aren't then it will silently recycle data into your frame (which is a logical problem and a chief complaint of mine about recycling arguments).

Ultimately, I think you need one of the following:

1. Assign the `gsub`ed version of `period` only for those rows where `detect` is true, returning `NA` for all other rows:

   ```r
   MR_all['period_3'] <- dplyr::case_when(
     detect == FALSE ~ gsub("\\D", "", MR_all$period)
   )
   ```
2. Same as above, but defaulting to `period` if it is not true.

   ```r
   MR_all['period_3'] <- dplyr::case_when(
     detect == FALSE ~ gsub("\\D", "", MR_all$period),
     TRUE ~ MR_all$period
   )
   ```

   or the preferred method in dplyr-1.1.0:

   ```r
   MR_all['period_3'] <- dplyr::case_when(
     detect == FALSE ~ gsub("\\D", "", MR_all$period),
     .default = MR_all$period
   )
   ```

Comment: Thank you @r2evans for your detailed answer. The code works but unfortunately the slash on the dates disappear. Is there a way I could change the code so that does not happen? T

Comment: I have no idea: when I use sample data from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75515230/3358272) and setup with `detect <- grepl("/", MR_all[[1]])`, the fourth entry does not lose the slashes. ('Course, this pattern clearly and irrevocably breaks rows 2-3, so ... not good.)