# How to use gsub

Tags: r, gsub

I am working in R with a data frame which has columns that contains dates. Some rows contains years such as 1687, others contains date formats such as 12/12/23 and others contains characters such as "First half of 19e century", "1876-1879", "between 19e-20e". I am trying to extract numerical values and the special characters / and - from this columns.

The way I went about it to extract numerical values from all rows expect the one that contains "/" because I want to keep those as it is. Here is my code:

```
MR_all = data.frame(
  period = c("First half of 19e century", "1876-1879", "between 19e-20e", "12/12/23")
)

detect<- grepl("/|-", MR_all$period)

MR_all['period_3'] <- dplyr::case_when(detect == FALSE ~ gsub("[^0-9 / -]", "", MR_all$period))
```

This does not work because the "/" and '-' disappear in the output. I'd really appreciate help in changing the code so it extracts numeric values and those special characters.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the desired output? I am a bit confused of what you want the end result to look like

Comment: @jpsmith I just want to extract the dates from the column. The issue is some if them are in actual date format such as "01/01/2023" ,some  are contained in strings" between 2e century and 7e century" and ranges "1876-1829". I want to specify the functions well enough that it only extracts dates that are contained in strings and ignore other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies not in the `gsub` but in the use of `case_when`. You should specify what happens if `detect` is `TRUE`. Assuming that the regexes are doing what you ave in mind you should rewrite your code as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
MR_all <- data.frame(
  period = c("First half of 19e century", "1876-1879", "between 19e-20e", "12/12/23")
)
MR_all %>%
   mutate(period_3 = case_when(!grepl("/|-", period) ~ gsub("[^[:digit:]]", "", period),
                               TRUE ~ period))
# # A tibble: 4 × 2
#   period                    period_3       
#   <chr>                     <chr>          
# 1 First half of 19e century 19              # no `/` or `-` -> remove non digits
# 2 1876-1879                 1876-1879       # `-` detected -> keep as is    
# 3 between 19e-20e           between 19e-20e # `-` detected -> keep as is
# 4 12/12/23                  12/12/23        # `/` detected -> keep as is
```